# Typescript PouchDB "Cannot find name 'Content'." errors when transpiling

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, npm, pouchdb

I've been working on an Ionic app for 3 months.
I've had no problems building this app and deploying it to mobile in the past.
Yesterday when I tried to deploy to mobile I hit an NPM dependency issue.
So I wiped the node_modules folder and did `npm install`.

Since then I haven't been able to build my app for mobile or browser testing due to Typscript throwing `Error: Failed to transpile program`.

There is a very long chain of other errors but they all focus around `@types/pouchdb-core`. The typescript error I'm seeing the most is `Cannot find namespace 'Core'.`

In the browser the chain ends with `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.` at a line of my own code. However that code was working yesterday and I haven't changed it since. I've only reinstalled the packages.

I found nothing when I googled the problem. I tried setting the package versions to a known good configuration and still got the errors. So this is probably something I'm doing wrong but I have no idea what. As I mentioned I had it working just yesterday. Things only went wrong when I updated the packages. As far as I know that's all I did. I didn't even touch the packages file.

All my packages are currently at the latest, and for `@types/pouchdb-core` that's `6.1.5`.

Here is a gist of the errors from the command line logs during `ionic serve`:

https://gist.github.com/leetheguy/9e10a27ffc2f853f2b03c5a9fad10710

Comment: i had similler issue using pouchDB with angular4 web application , but my issue was mainly because i was using the old angular-cli that was finding some issues in the new pouchdb library , but when i updated angular-cli to its latest version things worked fine for me, try updating ionic cli

Comment: I read about that solution when I googled. Ironically, it was actually updating Ionic CLI that caused it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that it wasn't anything I did wrong after all.

An update to the Ionic CLI caused a lot of changes to the package requirements. I think that every time they update the CLI something breaks actually. But it's usually not this bad.

The solution was to create a new app and copy over my `src` directory. Then I ran `ionic serve` and added all the packages it said were missing one at a time. I did it that way to guarantee only the minimal `package.json` setup necessary. Then I replaced the original app's `package.json` with the one from the new app. There were a couple more minor hiccups but it worked great.